# How to set condition in alias column in SQL Server? How to set less than condition in distance column?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  
    latitude, longitude, 
    SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (latitude - 29.0998573), 2) +
         POWER(69.1 * (76.3466209 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM 
    driverAvailable
```

Comment: Not with you can you clarify by example.

Comment: Just repeat the sqrt(...) stuff

Comment: I want to fetch record which is less than 25 in distance column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *either* repeat the formula for the `distance` in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  
    latitude, longitude, 
    SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (latitude - 29.0998573), 2) +
         POWER(69.1 * (76.3466209 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM 
    driverAvailable
WHERE 
    SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (latitude - 29.0998573), 2) +
         POWER(69.1 * (76.3466209 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) < 25
```

or you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) and then use the defined alias column:

```
WITH DistanceData AS
( 
    SELECT  
        latitude, longitude, 
        SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (latitude - 29.0998573), 2) +
             POWER(69.1 * (76.3466209 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
   FROM 
       driverAvailable
)
SELECT 
    latitude, longitude, distance
FROM
    DistanceData
WHERE
    distance < 25
```

You just cannot directly use the column alias in a `SELECT` query in your `WHERE` clause - you have to use something like a CTE to be able to do this